# Is this series positive?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are there ways to expand the following series or show it is positive?

$(1-\frac{x_1}{a})(1-\frac{x_2}{a})...(1-\frac{x_n}{a})$ where $a$ and $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq ... \leq x_n$ are positive.

I know I can show $a>x_n$, but I am looking for alternate ways.

Comment: How is $"a"$ defined?

Comment: There's insufficient information. Choose $x_1 = \cdots = x_n = \frac{a}{2}$ and we have that it is positive, choose $x_1 = \cdots = x_n = a$ and that gives it $0$, and finally $x_1 = \cdots = x_{n-1} = \frac{a}{2}$, $x_n = 2a$, and that makes it negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. If $x_i = a$ then it's $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\bigg(1-\frac{x_1}{a}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{x_2}{a}\bigg)\cdots\bigg(1-\frac{x_n}{a}\bigg)=a^n(a-x_1)(a-x_2)\cdot...\cdot(a-x_n)$$ By Vieta's formula
$$(a-x_1)(a-x_2)\dots(a-x_n)=a^n-(x_1+\dots+x_n)a^{n-1}+\dots+(-1)^n(x_1\dots x_n)$$
Hence, the expression can be expanded as
$$\bigg(1-\frac{x_1}{a}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{x_2}{a}\bigg)\cdots\bigg(1-\frac{x_n}{a}\bigg) =$$$$= a^{2n}-(x_1+\dots+x_n)a^{2n-1}+\dots+(-1)^n(x_1\dots x_n)a^n$$